# How to adjust the size of the Textbox with values of type Double?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm making a progress bar using a Textbox; it works perfectly but, for me to be able to bring more accurate values, I need to be able to adjust the its Width to decimal values, like 230.73 or 0.50.

I tried, but an alert appears saying it accepts only in `int32` format. Does anyone know if it is possible to use decimal values?

Comment: The textbox width represents the width in pixels. How should we draw a half pixel or 0.73 pixel?

Comment: We won't be able to help much without the relevant code.

Comment: Can't convert to double? If in programs like adobe xd I can increase the size with decimal numbers, why not in visual studio? We are talking about pixel and the 2 programs work with it, why does one work and the other doesn't?

Comment: this means that you're using a library like System.Windows.Forms, which has an integer coordinate system. This does not mean that 1 equals one pixel - the screen resolution settings and logical pixel width also come into play. Ultimately the output device will likely be quantized so what are you trying to achieve? you can always use a scale based on `double` to go as fine-grained as you need to, then scale down to logical and physical pixels.

Comment: Anything had to draw at the end on the screen respecting the pixels. So if any system can work with decimals/doubles the real integer pixel values are calulated from them. The magic behind all of it has a name: Math